# How to access the file using the relative path

Tags: html, css, relative-path

I've got the following folder hierarchy in my web application.

[image]

I'm using the following relative path to access my CSS files but the layout doesn't detect the CSS. There are two layouts but I'm calling the CSS from the layout file which resides inside the views folder.

This is the path I used to access the CSS file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/style.css">
```

I used this path too but no luck.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../style/style.css">
```

Please help!

Comment: This one should work: `../../style/style.css` Maybe there's something else wrong? What is the HTTP response for `style.css`?

Answer (score 0):

The second Path should be correct.
I also tried it in Visual Studio 2010 with the same folders as you and VS gives me the same Path (Second one) as you said.

Another Question, do you put the link into the header of the HTML page ?

```
<head>
     <link href="../../style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are not using multiple CSS files. And if you are using Chrome/FF you can check whether your CSS is called or not with tools like firebug.

You can see the full path with these tools.

Answer (score 0):

if your layout file loading in another file try that files path or simply use path like this

```
 <head>
     <link href="/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
```

your real layout can be work like this too

```
<head>
     <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<link type="text/css" href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```